# extract substring from string

Tags: text-processing, filenames

I need to extract the characters before the character '2.0.1', '2.0.12'. from string like
`sgdgfhfh-ZZZZZZ-ZZZ-2.0.1.ZZZ,sgdgfhfh-ZZZZZZ-ZZZ-2.0.12.ZZ :`

I am trying:

```
#!/bin/bash
c=grep -o '[.0-9]*[0-9]' $1 
echo $c
```

file `$1` is text file which contains `ZZZZZZ-ZZZ-2.0.1.ZZZ`, giving error:

```
line 2: -o: command not found
```

Comment: Is the string in the output of a process? In a file? In a variable?

Comment: Its a file name whose version i want to extract.

Comment: Please provide examples of input/output and paste what have you tried so far.

Comment: I am trying                                                                                       
 #!/bin/bash
c=grep -o '[.0-9]*[0-9]' $1
echo $c            file$1 is text file which contains ZZZZZZ-ZZZ-2.0.1.ZZZ,   giving error line 2: -o: command not found

Comment: please edit your question to include these clarifying details. Also: do these filenames have *two* versions (i.e. 2.01 and 2.012 above), or were those two separate filenames?

Comment: No only one version

Comment: 1) please format you code using the **{}** symbol. 2) use `c=$(grep -o ...)` as is: you are running the comand `-o` in an env where c is set to grep.

Comment: If you're happy with one of the answers, upvoting it (or several) and maybe even [accepting the most helpful one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) is the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Except `grep` you could try to use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*\.\)\{3,3\}.*$//'
```

**With input from** `echo`:

```
echo "sgdgfhfh-ZZZZZZ-ZZZ-2.0.12.ZZ" | sed 's/\([0-9]*\.\)\{3,3\}.*$//'
```

**In bash script**:

First, create a file:

```
nano script.sh
```

Add following code into a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1" | sed 's/\([0-9]*\.\)\{3,3\}.*$//'
```

Save and exit. Add execute permission:

```
chmod u+x script.sh
```

Run `script.sh` with input param (`$1` inside script)

```
./script.sh "sgdgfhfh-ZZZZZZ-ZZZ-2.0.12.ZZ"
```

Output will:

```
sgdgfhfh-ZZZZZZ-ZZZ-
```

**Sed pattern explanation**:

1. `'s/pattern/replace_string/'` - replace pattern. Find `pattern` and replace it to a `replace_string`
2. `\([0-9]*\.\)\{3,3\}` - find `\([0-9]*\.\)\` pattern which repeated three times `(\{3,3\})`

`\([0-9]*\.\)\` will correspond `0.`, `12.`, `2345345345.` and `.`

Answer (score 1):

As @Archemar said in his comment, your command

```
c=grep -o '[.0-9]*[0-9]' $1
```

doesn't execute `grep` at all. To set a variable to the output of a command, the syntax is:

```
c=$(grep -o '[.0-9]*[0-9]' $1)
```

`$(command)` will get replaced by the output of that command.

Now why do you get such a strange error message? Because it's valid to do a variable assignment before executing a command. This means to have that variable set for just this command. This can be useful if you don't want to set or change a variable permanently. So your line is interpreted as "the variable `c` is to be set to the string `grep` and then the command `-o` should be executed with arguments `'[.0-9]*[0-9]'` and `$1`, so a command `-o` is searched for, but not found.